# Parse Mongodb json query in java with multiple criteria

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to parse a java string to mongo DBObject or BasicDBObject as below.

```
List<DBObject> query = new ArrayList<DBObject>();

String allQry = "{ \"$match\" : { \"CUSTOMERID\" : { \"$gt\" : 10}}}, { \"$project\" : { \"CUSTOMERNAME\" : 1 , \"COUNTRY\" : 1 , \"CUSTOMERID\" : 1}},{ \"$sort\" : { \"COUNTRY\" : 1}}";

BasicDBObject dbobj = BasicDBObject.parse(allQry);

query.add(dbobj);

System.out.println("qqqquery : "+query);

Cursor aggCur = collection.aggregate(query, aggOpt);
```

After run above example codes, it outputs `qqqquery : [{ "$match" : { "CUSTOMERID" : { "$gt" : 10}}}]`. There are $match , $project and $sort in allQry. Why do not it includes `$project` and `$sort` in this query?  It only includes $match, who can help to check this reason? Thanks.

Comment: please format properly

Comment: Not able to understand your question. Please edit it to make it more readable.

Comment: You're ending the object in the middle. Replace all the `},{` with `,`. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: Thank your help to edit example code. I replace all },{ with , it will throw excepton com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 16435: 'A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.'

Comment: The error 16435 has an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39060221/a-pipeline-stage-specification-object-must-contain-exactly-one-field-with-php-mo

Comment: yes, i use my original allQry, it will not throw that exception. But, if I replace all },{ with ,  it will throw that exception.

Comment: try removing the first `}, {` or the second `}, {` only, see if it works. There seems to be a mistake in one of the second and third blocks. Your original query does not cause an error because it just ignores the second and third block.

Comment: `BasicDBObject` parses a document not an array. Parse each stage and add them to list.

Answer (score 0):

Following this tutorial:
http://pingax.com/trick-convert-mongo-shell-query-equivalent-java-objects/

you could add all parts of your query like this:

```
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient();
DB db = mongo.getDB("pingax");

DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("aggregationExample");

/*
 MONGO SHELL : db.aggregationExample.aggregate(
 {$match : {type : "local"}} ,
 {$project : { department : 1 , amount : 1 }}
 );
 */
 DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("type", "local")); 

 DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("$project", new BasicDBObject("department", 1).append("amount", 1));

 AggregationOutput output = coll.aggregate(match,project,group,sort);
```

Related:

- [How to find documents matching multiple criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24353580/how-to-find-documents-matching-multiple-criteria)
- [Executing Mongo like Query (JSON)through Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860728/executing-mongo-like-query-jsonthrough-java)

Comment: Thank your answer. But, this example can not resolve my issue. I need to convert all parts in java String to mongo DBObject.